# Database design for discord bot on multiple servers

Tags: database

My bot currently listens to new messages coming in, and if a message contains a keyword (different from a command) it will automatically log information about who posted that unique key into a database. If another person in that same server posted the same YT video, the bot would flag it as a repost (and reference the original post).

All this is working, but only for a single server. Multiple servers would cause the bot to tell a server that a link was posted in another, which it shouldn't care about.

Right now I am using Redis, because it was quick and easy to get started.

My question is, what would be a good way to get this bot to be useful in more than one server? That is, if someone posts the same youtube video from different servers, the bot shouldn't care and should log them individually. Currently, this would cause conflicts.

My thoughts were, I could just go with a traditional SQL db and just have a servers table that lists the servers the bot is in, so when I detect the YT message I will also join on the servers to determine if that is the same server or not.

Does this make sense, or is there maybe a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is another field with the server id. Then your search for duplicate entries should include that this entry needs to have the current server id, too.

I'm pretty sure you can do that with any database (Sql or NoSql) or any other storage/query mechanism.